# How to round numbers within dynamic pivot?

Tags: sql-server-2008

So i have this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(period)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT period FROM atbv_Accounting_Transactions WHERE lAccountNO LIKE '6%' AND Period LIKE '2017%') AS Periods

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    N'SELECT lAccountNo, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM (SELECT
    lAccountNo, period, SUM(Amount) As Total
    FROM atbv_Accounting_Transactions 
    WHERE lAccountNO LIKE ''6%'' AND Period LIKE ''2017%''
    GROUP BY lAccountNo, period
    ) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(TOTAL) 
          FOR period IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
 EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

It returns me this:

[image]

How do i remove decimal places within select itself. I cannot edit column in the table and reduce the decimal places.So i need to edit this query to return values without decimals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should just change  `SUM(Amount)` to  `cast(SUM(Amount) as int)` or perhaps `floor(SUM(Amount))` and it will do the trick.